# How to use JavaMail as a Web App with Parse.com Cloud Code

Tags: java, javascript, parse-platform, jakarta-mail, openshift

How do I make the JavaMail app (or an equivalent) into a usable web app, that is nothing more than the Java class (and its related .jar components)? I don't want a fancy web app with UI that I can access - just an applet that my Parse Javascript function can call upon, send data to, and thus send an email with.

Parse.com's Cloud Code only supports Javascript, and sending emails in JS is substantially more difficult than in Java. Plus, I have worked with the JavaMail app before.

I have looked into Openshift, Tomcat, and such, but I keep floundering in the insane technical details which I deem irrelevant for what I am trying to accomplish. What I want is much simpler: The .java file and its .jar's accessible and runnable from a Javascript HTTP Request. Can somebody guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of hosting providers that will allow you to deploy a Java application that uses JavaMail.  Google App Engine is one to consider.